# How do I extract data from json object? (fundamental question)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am trying to extract data from json data type. I am using an already made dependency that is from the npm dependencies, to be exact from this link, https://www.npmjs.com/package/malaysia-postcodes?activeTab=readme . For the context, I want to extract *cities* and *states* data from a *postcode(a.k.a zip code)*.

I've tried extracting the data as in the readme and I get all the states and cities. However, I am having trouble when trying to extract data from postcode(a.k.a zip code). When I tried using `{locations}`, I am getting an error 'Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {found, state, city}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.' . How can I use the data from this `const locations = findPostcode("17070");` ?

The following are my code and also the documentation picture from npm regarding `findPostCode("")` :

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {
  allPostcodes,
  getStates,
  getCities,
  getPostcodes,
  findPostcode
} from "malaysia-postcodes";

function App() {
  const postcodes = allPostcodes;
  const states = getStates();
  const cities = getCities("Sabah");
  const locations = findPostcode("17070");

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div>
        Postcode : <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
        City : <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
        States : <input type="text" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <ul> {cities} </ul>
          <ul> {states} </ul>

          <ul> {locations} </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. I just have to use `{locations.state}` and `{locations.city}`, this answer my question.

Comment: If this is just a case of a couple of typos should should probably just delete the question.